# Logic hook "After save" not working with Subpanel

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

I am trying to calculate total amount using logic hook.

I have two modules. `Accounts` and `Payments` having `1:M Relationship`

I have written logic hook `after save` in payments module.

```
$hook_array['after_save'][] = Array(1, 'Update pending amount and paid amount in case', 'custom/modules/Payments/logic_hooks_class.php','logic_hooks_class', 'after_save_method');
```

Its working if I add Payment directly from payment module. But when I trying to insert Payment in accounts module thorugh payment subpanel then its not calling after save logic hook.

I have also checked with `process record` logic hook.

Could you please someone help me resolve this. I am using `SuiteCRM 7.6.4`

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

For more info try this link [Click here ....](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Developer/Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.5/Module_Framework/Logic_Hooks/Module_Hooks/after_relationship_add/)

```
after_relationship_add
```

**Example**

./custom/modules/{module}/logic_hooks.php

```
    $hook_version = 1;
    $hook_array = Array();

    $hook_array['after_relationship_add'] = Array();
    $hook_array['after_relationship_add'][] = Array(
        //Processing index. For sorting the array.
        1,

        //Label. A string value to identify the hook.
        'after_relationship_add example',

        //The PHP file where your class is located.
        'custom/modules/{module}/logic_hooks_class.php',

        //The class the method is in.
        'logic_hooks_class',

        //The method to call.
        'after_relationship_add_method'
    );
```

/custom/modules/{module}/logic_hooks_class.php

```
    if (!defined('sugarEntry') || !sugarEntry) die('Not A Valid Entry Point');

    class logic_hooks_class
    {
        function after_relationship_add_method($bean, $event, $arguments)
        {
            // check $arguments.related_module == "Payments" 
            //logic
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not working.. Its not calling after_relationship_add_method

Comment: Which module did you add the after relationship add hook to?